# How can I transform a string to a list in tensorflow?

Tags: string, list, tensorflow

I have in a line of csv someting as "1,2,'["Action","Childre"]'"
and I want to decode user tensorflow to read the first to entrance as int and the last one as a tensor.

```
CSV_COLUMNS=["movieId","userId","genre"]

LABEL_COLUMN="genre"

columns = tf.decode_csv('2,3,\"[\'Action,Children\']\"',record_defaults= [0.0,0.0,""])

features = dict(zip(CSV_COLUMNS, columns))

label = features.pop(LABEL_COLUMN)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(features)
    sess.run(label)
```

the result is 
{'movieId': 2.0, 'userId': 3.0}
b"['hola']"

but I want that the last result shows
array(["hola"])

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can strip `['` and `']` from string using `tf.strings.substr` and then split string into an array using `tf.string_split`. 
Note that output is a `SparseTensor`.

```
label = tf.strings.substr(label, 2, tf.strings.length(label) - 4)
splitted = tf.string_split(tf.expand_dims(label, 0), ',')
```